# Rustでミスマッチタイプエラーが発生したが、具体的に何をしたら良いのかわからない

Tags: rust

Windows10環境下です。
Rustのソースをビルドした時、以下のエラーが発生しました。

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src\main.rs:25:43
   |
25 |   let a:Result<Channel, Box<dyn Error>> = example_feed();
   |         -------------------------------   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected enum `Result`, found opaque type
   |         |
   |         expected due to this
   |
note: while checking the return type of the `async fn`
  --> src\main.rs:14:28
   |
14 | async fn example_feed() -> Result<Channel, Box<dyn Error>> {
   |                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ checked the `Output` of this `async fn`, found opaque type
   = note:     expected enum `Result<Channel, Box<dyn std::error::Error>>`
           found opaque type `impl Future<Output = Result<Channel, Box<(dyn std::error::Error + 'static)>>>`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0308`.
```

ソースは以下です。

```
async fn example_feed() -> Result<Channel, Box<dyn Error>> {
    let content = reqwest::get("https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.rss")
        .await?
        .bytes()
        .await?;
    let channel = Channel::read_from(&content[..])?;
    Ok(channel)
}

#[tauri::command]
fn get_rss(_state: tauri::State<StateValue>) -> String {
  let a:Result<Channel, Box<dyn Error>> = example_feed();
  match a{
    Ok(result)=> println!("{:?}",result),
    Err(msg)=>println!("No"),
  }
  
  String::from("test")
}
```

掲題の通り、具体的に何をどう修正したら良いのか、わかりません。
私は何をしたら良いのでしょうか？

*追記

awaitを使用したところ、次から次へとコンパイラから指示が飛び、
最終的に以下のソースとエラーとなりました。

```
error[E0597]: `__tauri_message__` does not live long enough
  --> src\main.rs:23:1
   |
23 | #[tauri::command]
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^-
   | |               |
   | |               `__tauri_message__` dropped here while still borrowed
   | borrowed value does not live long enough
   | argument requires that `__tauri_message__` is borrowed for `'static`
...
37 |         .invoke_handler(tauri::generate_handler![get_rss])
   |                         --------------------------------- in this macro invocation
   |
   = note: this error originates in the macro `__cmd__get_rss` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0597`.
warning: `app` (bin "app") generated 1 warning
error: could not compile `app` due to previous error; 1 warning emitted
```

ソース

```
#![cfg_attr(
    all(not(debug_assertions), target_os = "windows"),
    windows_subsystem = "windows"
)]

use std::error::Error;
use rss::Channel;
struct StateValue(i32);

async fn example_feed() -> Result<Channel, Box<dyn Error>> {
    let content = reqwest::get("https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.rss")
        .await?
        .bytes()
        .await?;
    let channel = Channel::read_from(&content[..])?;
    Ok(channel)
}

#[tauri::command]
async fn get_rss(_state: tauri::State<'_,StateValue>) -> String {
  let a:Result<Channel, Box<dyn Error>> = example_feed().await;
  match a{
    Ok(result)=> println!("{:?}",result),
    Err(msg)=>println!("No"),
  }
  
  String::from("test")
}

fn main() {
    tauri::Builder::default()
        .manage(StateValue(0))
        .invoke_handler(tauri::generate_handler![get_rss])
        .run(tauri::generate_context!())
        .expect("error while running tauri application");
}
```

何をどうしたら良いのか、さっぱりわかりません……

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tauriには詳しくないですが、手元で実験してみた感じでは`#[tauri::command]`を付ける関数は`async`にできないようです。

つまり、`example_feed()`を`async`でない通常の関数に書き換えるか、あるいは`async`関数が返してくる`Future`を解決してやる必要があります。

1. `example_feed()`を書き換えるパターン
   `reqwest`には[`async`を使わない`blocking`という機能](https://github.com/seanmonstar/reqwest#blocking-client)があります。
   この機能を有効にすると`example_feed()`は通常の関数として書けます。

```rust
fn example_feed() -> Result<Channel, Box<dyn Error>> {
    let content = reqwest::blocking::get("https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.rss")?
        .bytes()?;
    let channel = Channel::read_from(&content[..])?;
    Ok(channel)
}
```

2. `Future`を解決するパターン
   `Future`から値を取り出すには、非同期ランタイムに`Future`を渡して実行してもらう必要があります。
   `tauri`は運よく非同期ランタイムを持っているので、それを使って`Future`を解決できます。

```rust
#[tauri::command]
fn get_rss(_state: tauri::State<'_, StateValue>) -> String {
    // tauri::async_runtime::block_on で Future を解決
    let a: Result<Channel, Box<dyn Error>> = tauri::async_runtime::block_on(example_feed());
    match a {
        Ok(result) => println!("{:?}", result),
        Err(msg) => println!("No"),
    }

    String::from("test")
}
```

Comment: 解決しました！ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 2):

- [Compile error for async stateful commands that don't return a Result #2533](https://github.com/tauri-apps/tauri/issues/2533)

という不具合があり、ワークアラウンドとしては、次のいずれかを行えば良いようです。

- `async` を使わない
- (使っていないのであれば) state 引数を除去する
- 戻り値の型を `Result` にする

改めて見直してみると、公式のサンプルコードでは確かに戻り値は `Result` 型になっています。

- https://tauri.studio/v1/guides/features/command/#complete-example
- https://github.com/tauri-apps/tauri/blob/f1637d6/examples/commands/main.rs#L114-L121

```rust
async fn example_feed() -> Result<Channel, Box<dyn Error>> {
    let content = reqwest::get("https://www.soumu.go.jp/news.rdf")
        .await?
        .bytes()
        .await?;
    let channel = Channel::read_from(&content[..])?;
    Ok(channel)
}

#[tauri::command]
async fn get_rss(_state: tauri::State<'_, StateValue>) -> Result<String, ()> {
    let a: Result<Channel, Box<dyn Error>> = example_feed().await;
    match a {
        Ok(result) => {
            println!("{:?}", result);
        }
        Err(msg) => {
            println!("No");
        }
    }

    Ok(String::from("test"))
}
```

あるいは

```rust
async fn example_feed() -> Result<Channel, Box<dyn Error>> {
    // 略
}

#[tauri::command]
async fn get_rss() -> String {
    let a: Result<Channel, Box<dyn Error>> = example_feed().await;
    match a {
        Ok(result) => {
            println!("{:?}", result);
        }
        Err(msg) => {
            println!("No");
        }
    }

    String::from("test")
}
```

(`async` を外す例は[別回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/88993/2808)にあるので省略)

Answer (score -2):

rustは存じ上げませんが、example_feed()をawaitしてみてはいかがでしょうか？